# IOS 8 and Touch ID

Tags: ios, touch-id

Any possibility of using the finger print scanner on an ipad to simply get an image of the fingerprint without actually doing any authentication?

The OS seems to do it when you enter your finger print into the device but the only documentation I can find is for Local Authentication.

Comment: Apple doesn't allow that because it would cause a security risk.  You may be able to get around it with private APIs, but that will get your app rejected from the App Store.

Comment: I've removed the question about Android's fingerprint sensor, please ask a second question about that, the platforms are very different and so will the answers be different.

Answer (score 4):

No, you can't, not even with a private API.

From: http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT5949

> Touch ID doesn't store any images of your fingerprint. It stores only
>   a mathematical representation of your fingerprint. It isn't possible
>   for someone to reverse engineer your actual fingerprint image from
>   this mathematical representation. The chip in your device also
>   includes an advanced security architecture called the Secure Enclave
>   which was developed to protect passcode and fingerprint data.
>   Fingerprint data is encrypted and protected with a key available only
>   to the Secure Enclave. Fingerprint data is used only by the Secure
>   Enclave to verify that your fingerprint matches the enrolled
>   fingerprint data. The Secure Enclave is walled off from the rest of
>   the chip and the rest of iOS. Therefore, iOS and other apps never
>   access your fingerprint data, it's never stored on Apple servers, and
>   it's never backed up to iCloud or anywhere else. Only Touch ID uses
>   it, and it can't be used to match against other fingerprint databases.

Comment: I understand it doesn't store the fingerprint but for example when you are entering a fingerprint into the system it draws a nice little representation of the ridges and lines of your fingers. Is that bogus or just something we don't have access to?

Comment: It's bogus lol, no matter what finger you use the image is the same.